# A non-vanishing Betti number of punctured manifolds

Tags: manifolds, homology-cohomology, betti-numbers

Let $M$ be the oriented $m$-manifold. Futhermore, $M$ is not closed. Then how we show that $\beta_{m-1}(M-\{P_{1},\ldots,P_{n}\})=\beta_{m-1}(M)+n,$ where $M-\{P_{1},\ldots,P_{n}\}$ is n-times punctured manifold.

Comment: Maybe with the Mayer-Vietoris sequence?